# How to replicate a row of an array with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to replicate the last row of an array in python and  found the following lines of code in the numpy documentation

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> np.repeat(x, [1, 2], axis=0)
```

in the above code what does the second parameter "[1,2]" in np.repeat  do?
if i want to replicate a row in a 3*3 array how will this second parameter change.

Comment: Second argument of repeat specify how many times each element should be repeated. Can you provide your sample output? I would be much easier to provide an answer if output is there

Comment: Dark's answer nicely elaborate the behaviour of `np.repeat`. However you should also have a look at `np.tile` and decide how you are willing to repeat rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the *repeats* parameter

> **repeats** : int or array of ints
>
> The number of repetitions for each element. *repeats* is broadcasted to fit the shape of the given axis.

It's the number of times you want to repeat a row or column based on the parameter axis.

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]])
np.repeat(x, repeats = [1, 2, 1 ], axis=0)
```

This would lead to repetition of row 1 once, row 2 twice and row 3 once.

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4], 
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5]])
```

Similarly, if you specify the `axis = 1`. Repeats can take maximum of 2 elements in the list,and below code lead to repetition of column 1 once and column 2 twice.

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]])
np.repeat(x, repeats = [1, 2 ], axis=1)

array([[1, 2, 2],
       [3, 4, 4],
       [4, 5, 5]])
```

If you want to repeat only last row, repeat only last row and stack i.e

```
rep = 2
last = np.repeat([x[-1]],repeats= rep-1 ,axis=0)

np.vstack([x, last])

array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 5]])
```

Comment: I have another question suppose i have a very large array say 100*100 then if i want to replicate the last row how would i do so would it be like [1,1,1,1....2] or is there a shorter way of doing so?

Answer (score 2):

I have test it using following code

```
    >>> a
    array([[1, 2],
           [3, 4]])
    >>> np.repeat(a, [2,3], axis = 0)
    array([[1, 2],
           [1, 2],
           [3, 4],
           [3, 4],
           [3, 4]])
    >>> np.repeat(a, [1,3], axis = 0)
    array([[1, 2],
           [3, 4],
           [3, 4],
           [3, 4]])
```

The second parameter seems mean how many times the i-th elements in a will be repeat. As my code shown above, [2,3] repeats a[0] 2 times and repeats a[1] 3 times, [1,3] repeats a[0] 1 times and repeats a[1] 3 times